# Iterating an array in an object in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple quiz and discovering my Javascript skills are a lot worse than I thought they were.

I have an array of questions:

```
var questions = [
{
    question: "Question1",
    choices: ["A","B","C"],
    answer: 0
},
//etc. x 5
];
```

This code works for inserting each questions.question into each of the 5 section h1s:

```
$('section h1').each(function(index) {
        $(this).text(questions[index].question);
});
```

But this code for inserting each questions.choices puts questions[0].choices[0] ("A") in the first li, questions[1].choices[1] ("E") in the second li, and questions[2].choices[2] ("I") in the third li of the first section. The other four sections have nothing in their lis.

```
$('section li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(questions[index].choices[index]);
});
```

How can I fix this so that each choice gets put in its own li for the section relevant to its question? For instance, section one h1 = Question1, lis A, B and C, section two h1 = Question2, lis D, E, F, and so on.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/sbv2jj9m/

Comment: Ok. Show us the input *AND* the expected output. Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: Can you not just stick that second portion inside the first portion, and rename one of the index variables?

Comment: @Madbreaks sorry, this is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/sbv2jj9m/

Comment: It's not very complicated -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zeLLoawz/**

Comment: Your fiddle would be a little different -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sbv2jj9m/1/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine your two iterators into one, and just do this:

```
$('section').each(function(index) {
    // Set H1 text
    $('h1', this).text(questions[index].question);
    // Set list items
    $('li', this).each(function(i){
        $(this).text(questions[index].choices[i]);
    });
});
```

Note that you're iterating over the `<section>` elements, then acting on sub elements of each.  The interior iterator has its own index, `i`.

```js
$(function(){

 var questions = [
 {
  question: "Question1",
  choices: ["A", "B", "C"], 
  answer: 2
 },
 {
  question: "Question2",
  choices: ["D", "E", "F"], 
  answer: 0
 },
 {
  question: "Question3",
  choices: ["G", "H", "I"], 
  answer: 1
 },
 {
  question: "Question4",
  choices: ["J", "K", "L"], 
  answer: 2
 },
 {
  question: "Question5",
  choices: ["M", "N", "O"], 
  answer: 1
 }

 ];
    
    $('section').each(function(index) {
        // Set H1 text
     $('h1', this).text(questions[index].question);
        // Set list items
        $('li', this).each(function(i){
            $(this).text(questions[index].choices[i]);
        });
 });

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1></h1>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <h1></h1>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <h1></h1>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <h1></h1>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <h1></h1>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I took. Is this close to what you're looking for? [Demo here](http://jsbin.com/kanifa/1/edit?js,output)

**JS**

```
var questions = [
{
  question: "Question1",
  choices: ["A","B","C"],
  answer: 0
},{
  question: "Question2",
  choices: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  answer: 1
}];


questions.forEach(function (q,index) {
  var section = $('body').append('<section></section>');
  var queston = section.append('<h1>'+q.question+'</h1>');
  var choices = section.append('<ul></ul>');

  for (var i=0; i<q.choices.length; i++) {
    choices.append('<li>'+q.choices[i]+'</li>');
  }

  var answer = section.append('<span>Answer: '+q.choices[q.answer]+'</span>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to advance to the next choice and you do that by updating index with `[index +1]` and perhaps you'd want to put that into your on document open... So something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('h1').each(function(index) {
$(this).text(questions(index + 1) + choices[index]);
}
```